# Angular 11 HttpClient Generic Observable map service values into a Class

Tags: node.js, angular, observable, httpclient, subscribe

I'm consuming a POST service in .net that returns the next structure, the service return data correctly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJxai.png)

```
public sendExcelInBase64ToBackEnd(data: any) {
    this.customOptions = {
        headers: this.customHttp.buildHeader(),
    };

    this.customHttp.Post<SerialResultDTO>('/serialsExcel', data, this.customOptions).subscribe(val => { // <- val data returns ok
        this.serialResult = val;
        let x = this.serialResult.Success;
        console.log(x);
        console.log(val.Success); // <- prints undefined
    })
    
    return null;
}
```

When I try print in console 'val.Success' it prints undefined!!, Why this happens??

I want assign all atributes to a custom class in angular, but in chrome debug it shows object data, but in time of asign to my model class it gets undefined!!

Someone can help me please!! I appreciate that!!

Comment: Hi Chris, does your `val` have a `Success` property. It is going to try to serialize it to `SerialResultDTO` so that should have a `Success` property.

Comment: Hi John, yes SerialResultDTO has the Success property, but the mistake was the spelling, the http service returns in lowercase like moxximanagarm says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image shows a lowercase `success`, but you try to log a titlecase `Success`. Change to

```
public sendExcelInBase64ToBackEnd(data: any) {
    this.customOptions = {
        headers: this.customHttp.buildHeader(),
    };

    this.customHttp.Post<SerialResultDTO>('/serialsExcel', data, this.customOptions).subscribe(val => {
        this.serialResult = val;
        let x = this.serialResult.success;
        console.log(x);
        console.log(val.success);
    })
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks moxximanagarm your are correct, the service returns in lowercase, I changed It and It works now!!!

Comment: Hi @Chris. R. , happy that you got the needed answer, you may like to mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote it?. That will motivate others to reserve more of their time for answering questions and helping eachothers.